# AttributeError: 'TextToVideoSDPipeline' object has no attribute '_offload_gpu_id'

Tags: python, google-colaboratory, huggingface

I encountered an issue while running the following code in a Colab notebook:

```
!pip install openai elevenlabs diffusers transformers accelerate pytorch-lightning git+https://github.com/huggingface/diffusers
from diffusers import DiffusionPipeline, DPMSolverMultistepScheduler
pipe = DiffusionPipeline.from_pretrained("cerspense/zeroscope_v2_576w", torch_dtype=torch.float16)
pipe.scheduler = DPMSolverMultistepScheduler.from_config(pipe.scheduler.config)
pipe.enable_model_cpu_offload()
```

This code was functional yesterday, but today, I'm getting the error message:

```
"AttributeError: 'TextToVideoSDPipeline' object has no attribute '_offload_gpu_id'"
```

I'm not sure why this error has started occurring, and I'm looking for insights or solutions to resolve it. Any help would be greatly appreciated.